# How to pass new values to props of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I need to re-render child elements with new props when I get new action.

Here is my App:

```js
export const App: FC = memo(() => {
  const [appState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { notes: [], id: -1 });
  const assistantStateRef = useRef<AssistantAppState>();
  const assistantRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof createAssistant>>();
  const ChangePage = async (page: string) => {
      history.push(page);
  }
  const history = createBrowserHistory();
  var appeal = ""
  var vuid = ""
  const forceUpdate = useReducer(() => ({}), {})[1] as () => void

  useEffect(() => {
    assistantRef.current = initializeAssistant(() => assistantStateRef.current);
    assistantRef.current.on("data", ({ action }: any) => {
      if (action) {
        console.log(action)
        switch (action.type) {

          case "init-user":
            appeal = action["character"]["appeal"]
            vuid = action.user_id;
            forceUpdate()
            break
     }})
     
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <PMain userID={vuid} appealR={appeal} {...props} />  } >
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
  );
```

How can I update `PMain` with new props after receiving an action of type `init-user`?

Comment: You may want to hold on to rendering the router until you have got all the data from `init-user`

Comment: use state for your `vuid` and `appeal` and update it so that it triggers a re-render .

Comment: Could you show me please how it's possible to implement? I have no idea...

Comment: @Shyam should I do something like `const [vuid, setUID] = useState("")` and later use `setUID(action.user_id)`? I don't know why but this does not help.